Importing KMZ photos to QGIS based on KMZ coordinates ("Import geotagged photos" does not work)
I have seen many topics on importing KMZ photos (like this for example: Showing images linked with corresponding KMZ in QGIS), however neither of them helps my situation
My photos are georeferenced, but I don't want to use my photos coordinates. I want to use exactly my KMZ coordinates.
Reason: I use an field app that allows me to generate a KMZ with adjusted points. I visually adjust my photo's point when I save it. It is very important and helpful as smartphones' GPS is not accurate.
How could I directly import my KMZ point with my photos attached to it?
